# Java - When I type nothing in input I get red errors

Tags: java, tags

My program works exactly how I want it to work, but when I leave the question blank or click okay, my output has all these errors in red.  I was wondering how I can fix that, so when I type nothing I should get null or an empty string.  I believe that the following program that I have screws it up, but I need this data to make my program work.  Is there something I'm missing to make sure I can get null or an empty string.

Thanks!

```
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ask any question (Remember to type the ?):");
i = input.length() - 1;
lastletter = input.charAt(i);
```

Comment: These errors are `Exception`s thrown. Please copy and paste it here, so we can see which exception it is and what is the stack trace.

Comment: All those errors in red are generated so that you can diagnose the error by reading the error message. Read it. Carefully.

Comment: Refer to this for details @ user1743969 : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)

Comment: Thanks for your help! :D I solved it, still have a problem when I'm inside a loop it doesn't work, but hopefully it works.

Answer (score 4):

When nothing is entered, `input.length()` returns `0`. Then you take `0-1` and get that `i` contains `-1`. Then you are trying to get the characte on index `-1` in the empty input. You have to check if `input.length()` equals `0` before you retrive the last letter.

Answer (score 2):

When you enter nothing, `input` becomes `""`. As a result, `input.length() - 1` evaluates to `-1`, meaning you're calling `input.charAt(-1)`. This causes a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` to be thrown, producing your "red error".

Answer (score 1):

The String's `chatAt(index)` returns any character at specified index, where the range of the index can be 0 to string's length minus 1 ie. `string.lenght()-1` and has to be positive.
Any index out of this range will give you `IndexOutOfBoundsException .

So in your particular case,

```
i = input.length() - 1;
lastletter = input.charAt(i);
```

When you entered nothing, input.length() returns 0 , hence i becomes -1. 
Since java specification says the valid range for charAt() is from 0 to input.length()-1   where input.length()-1 has to be positive, your code throws  `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

you can avoid it by checking if  index 'i' is negative ex:

```
i = input.length() - 1;
if (!i<0){
   lastletter = input.charAt(i);
}
```

Refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ask any question (Remember to type the ?):");
```

will return an empty string ("") if the user clicks okay without entering any text. The length of this string is zero, and trying to access the character at index -1 will throw an indexOutOfBoundsException. This can easily be fixed with checking the length of the input. But before you do that, you need to check if input equals null, because that's what will be returned if the user presses cancel or the top-right 'x'. So the check you need is:

```
if (input != null && input.length()  > 0){
   lastletter = input.charAt(input.length - 1);
}
```